# Flutter build ios error: Encountered error while building for device

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I encounter an error while I try to build my app for ios by `flutter build ios`. The error is related with `flutter_tools` packages. I tried to clean up my project with:

1. `flutter clean`
2. Delete `Podfile.lock` and re-run `pod install` in `ios/` directory
3. Delete `ios/Pods` directory

I don't have other ideea what to do. Here is my entire error log:

```
[+1019 ms] "flutter ios" took 14,767ms.
[   +4 ms] Encountered error while building for device.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      _BuildIOSSubCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_ios.dart:256:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[ +196 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 107ms
[        ] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hook priority 4
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

And here is my `flutter doctor --verbose` :

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at /Users/ovidiuusvat/Flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (4 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ovidiuusvat/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM G970F (mobile)                              • RF8MA07GHKP                          • android-arm64  •
      Android 11 (API 30)
    • iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (mobile) • 7E3ECED2-13E7-465A-A1A1-077EF6EFFEE9 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                                   • chrome                               • web-javascript •
      Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hello @Ovidiu Uşvat, did you resolve this?

Comment: I have the exact same error, have you found an answer?

Comment: Sorry but i don't remember exactly how I solved the error. Can you try to run the project from xCode and after run `flutter build ios`

Comment: Can somebody share the answer for this issue ?

Comment: Are you using Flutter 2.2.0? Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218376/xcode-version-12-4-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/67735768#67735768

Comment: At that time i was using Flutter 2.0.1

Answer (score 0):

For me the solutions for your error was `flutter create .`