# Xcode Version 12.4 "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" on macCatalina

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have the problem that I can no longer simulate my apps via Xcode, neither on the simulator (any device), nor on the real device.

I constantly get the error code:

Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description

...with different warnings underneath.

The following happened: All projects worked fine. Then I downloaded the package "nfc_manager 3.0.0+1" in addition to my already integrated package "nfc_in_flutter". Since this did not work, I deleted the nfc_manager package again. A short time later, this error occurred. I don't know if it has anything to do with this, but maybe it helps.

Now I can't simulate any of my projects via Xcode.

I have tried every conceivable solution I found on Stack Overflow about this issue - without any success.
In addition, I have logged in and logged out of keychain, restarted the mac, and completely uninstalled and re-downloaded Xcode.

Please help.

```html
nico@Nicos-MBP ios % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.2.0-11.0.pre.215, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
nico@Nicos-MBP ios % xcdoe clean
zsh: command not found: xcdoe
nico@Nicos-MBP ios % clean xcode
zsh: command not found: clean
nico@Nicos-MBP ios % flutter clean
Changing current working directory to: /Users/nico/AndroidStudioProjects/corona_impf_it
Cleaning Xcode workspace...                                         3,4s
Deleting build...                                                  379ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              66ms
Deleting .packages...                                                0ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       0ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            0ms
Deleting Flutter.podspec...                                          0ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         0ms
nico@Nicos-MBP ios % flutter run
Changing current working directory to: /Users/nico/AndroidStudioProjects/corona_impf_it
Running "flutter pub get" in corona_impf_it...                     936ms
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             10,8s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           224,7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
```

Comment: I have the same, except I only updated to Flutter 2.2.0. Before it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Flutter 2.2.0 and updated to hotfix 2.2.1 which resolves the issue.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel

Comment: Yes, this solved it for me. Thanks for the pointer.